# ¿Colocar un slider o barra de progreso tras presionar un <button>?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, css

Hola genere un formulario con HTML

```
<form class="form-login" action="reporte_Prisma.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <br>
        <img id="archivo" src="img/iconos/texto.png" height="200" width="200">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="archivo" accept=".txt" required=""><br><br>
        <button class="buttons">Cargar archivo .txt</button>
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Puede parecer poco, pero al dar clic en el input se ejecutan funciones y procedimientos almacenador en la Base de Datos, se tarda hasta 1 minuto en acabar de procesar todo

¿Cómo puedo colocar un slider o barra de progreso para que el usuario vea que la consulta esta siendo procesada?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses una librería para ello. La mejor que conozco es [nProgress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress).

Debes descargar los dos archivos de github:

- nprogress.js
- nprogress.css

Agregarlos a tu proyecto:

```html
<script src='nprogress.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='nprogress.css'/>
```

Y luego solo necesitas llamar cuando el `fetch` empieza y cuando resuelve:

```js
NProgress.start();
NProgress.done();
```

Comment: Lo intentaré, muchas gracias